# How to check if a column value is null in a datatable in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

So what i'm trying to do, is to loop through the datatable's column to get the value out of it.

For example, this is my datatable

```
emp_id      f_name         email            remarks
1            Jim          Jim@yahoo.com
2            Apple        apple@gmail.com  
3            Peter
4            Amy          amy@gmail.com
```

In this datatable, you can see that Peter's email is missing. I want to retrieve this record set a values in remarks "No email".

How can I do this?

Comment: Edit question and add your existing code for getting data

Comment: Would you please tell us some detail.How retrieve your data?
I guess you should use DbNull for checking. but let us know more about your code

Comment: for Example if you use Linq, you can do the same :
MyData.Select(x=> new MyRow{x.em_id,x.f_name,email=string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.email)?"No Email":x.Email});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Select("email is NULL or email=''"))
{
   dr["Remarks"]="No Email";
}
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

The above will set value of column "Remarks" as required.

Comment: modified code to set value of remarks column. Please check

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond. I am just wondering what if I want to check if it is null or empty as well? Is dt.Select() basically a SQL query?

Comment: @DragonBorn Check my comment in your question.
Select is a Linq Command

Comment: @MahdiFarhani Thanks. I missed it

Comment: modified my answer to include rows with empty email. please check

Answer (score 2):

Try this query, so you don't have to retrieve and modify the DataTable:

```
select  emp_id,
        f_name,
        email,
        ISNULL(email,'No Email') AS 'remark'
from [tablename]
```

if you want to retrieve only the null email add where in the query like this

```
 select  emp_id,
            f_name,
            email,
            ISNULL(email,'No Email') AS 'remark'
    from [tablename] where email is null
```

if you are using MySQL, replace `ISNULL` to `IFNULL`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this in LINQ:

```
var noemaillist = (from m in databaseContext.TableName
                  where m.email == String.Empty
                  select m).ToList();
if(noemaillist != null)
{
   foreach(var item in noemaillist)
   {
      item.remarks = "No email";
   }
}
databaseContext.SubmitChanges();
```

This will return the list with empty email id's and set the remarks column to "No email" for the corresponding empty email fields.

Comment: What about this. " I want to retrieve this record set a values in remarks "No email"."

Comment: Yeah as @RahulNikate pointed your solution would only filter out the empty email address's and do not update the 'Remarks'

Comment: oops... i missed it... thanks for reminding.. Rahil and fujiFX

Comment: How? noemaillist contains only items which has empty string in email column

Answer (score 1):

```
  foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                  var x=row[col.ColumnName].ToString();
                  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                  {
                      var colName = col.ColumnName.ToString();
                      row["remarks"] = string.Format("{0} is required", colName);
                  }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

in ADO.NET, there is property of `IsDBNull(<column>)`, in LINQ you may check it by `email != NULL`